# Android Browser page loading events

Tags: android, android-browser

I have made and application that fires the browser for a given URL.

Is it possible to detect Android browser page loading progress, so that I can display some interactive toast messages until the page completely loads on browser?

With a web view it works. But I don't know how to detect page loading events of a browser.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to get the event from the browser for the page loading or any other. since it is the entire other application and we cannot track it.